# Parsing date and AM/PM using java 8 DateTime API

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I'm trying to parse a date time string using java 8 DateTime API.

The string to parse contains date, month, year and AM/PM marker such as `17/02/2015 PM`.
I use the following pattern: `dd/MM/yyyy aa` and I expect the parsed LocalDateTime time part to be set at `12:00:00` or `00:00:00` depending on the AM/PM marker.

Using the former `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` API, the parsing works as expected using this pattern.

But when i use java 8 DateTime API and run the following code:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("17/02/2015 PM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy aa"));
```

I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many pattern letters: a
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.parseField(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1765)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.parsePattern(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1604)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendPattern(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1572)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DateTimeFormatter.java:534)
```

If i switch the pattern to `dd/MM/yyyy a` then i got the folowing exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '17/02/2015 PM' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {AmPmOfDay=1},ISO resolved to 2015-02-17 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1918)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1853)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {AmPmOfDay=1},ISO resolved to 2015-02-17 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:461)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime$$Lambda$7/474675244.queryFrom(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:226)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {AmPmOfDay=1},ISO resolved to 2015-02-17 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalTime.from(LocalTime.java:409)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:457)
    ... 5 more
```

It's also weird that when i do the reverse operation, format, it works fine:

```
 System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2015, 02, 17, 0, 0, 0).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy a")));
 System.out.println(LocalDateTime.of(2015, 02, 17, 12, 0, 0).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy a")));
```

respectively prints `17/02/2015 AM` and `17/02/2015 PM`.

The javadoc for `java.time.DateTimeFormatter` says (§Resolving, step #6):

> 6. A LocalTime is formed if there is at least an hour-of-day available. This involves providing default values for minute, second and fraction of second.

What i understand is that the field hour-of-day is mandatory to parse a LocalDateTime... Isn't there any way to parse the time part only using the AM/PM field only?

Comment: Uhm, well, you have AM and PM but no associated time... What do you expect the date to be parsed to?

Comment: I expect the time part to be set at 12:00:00 or 00:00:00. It used to work with `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Well, it is a strange corner case that `SimpleDateFormat` is even able to parse that; after all it's not even a valid date. Why don't you have the date being formatted correctly to begin with?

Comment: Yep, it's probably a corner case in `SimpleDateFormat`. If i was responsible for formatting the date i would certainly have used an ISO DateTime format... :-) I did not find a solution by myself, so i'm just asking if someone has one... If it's just not supported, i will certainly find another solution like add hour and minute fields or something...

Comment: If there is only AM/PM-information in the text to be parsed then it is not logical that the time must be midnight or noon. It could be any time because AM/PM just determines which **half of day** is relevant. The designers of JSR-310 (java.time-package) were correct to reject such a situation where the library is asked to invent data out of thin air. At least the hour of am/pm is needed here as supplement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the default values for unavailable fields via [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("dd/MM/yyyy a")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_AMPM, 0) // this is required
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0) // optional, but you can set other value
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0) // optional as well
    .toFormatter();
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("17/02/2015 PM", formatter)); // 2015-02-17T12:00
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("17/02/2015 AM", formatter)); // 2015-02-17T00:00
```